# Query to read on composite columns in cassandra hector

Tags: cassandra, hector

I need to read all values in a cassandra column family according to the row key.
I am getting only for one row key. I want to query for all the keys in the column family.

Schema of the column family

> rowKey is String and the values are in the column names itself like date:subject:marks
>   i.e saved like this in the db 2013-04-13 00:00:00 UTC,science,99 for rowkey=1

trying like this

```
  Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("Test Cluster", "localhost:9160");
  Keyspace keyspaceOperator = HFactory.createKeyspace(student, cluster);
  System.out.println( "Connected to cassandra " + cluster);
  String rowKey = "1";


  SliceQuery<String,String,String> columnQuery = HFactory.createSliceQuery(keyspaceOperator, StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get());
  columnQuery.setColumnFamily("studentInfo").setKey(rowKey).setRange(null, null, false, 100);
  System.out.println(columnQuery);
  QueryResult<ColumnSlice<String,String>> result = columnQuery.execute();
  for (HColumn<String, String> column : result.get().getColumns()) {
    System.out.println(column.getName());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this???

```
      SliceQuery<String,String,String> columnQuery = HFactory.createSliceQuery(ksp, StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get());
      columnQuery.setColumnFamily("studentInfo").setKey(rowKey).setColumnNames("id","name");
      QueryResult<ColumnSlice<String,String>> result = columnQuery.execute();
```

Comment: yes this works but only for one row i am not able to iterate over all rows in the keyspace.. Also columns in my keyspace dont have a label they are saved in column names like `1 | 2013-04-01,science,96`

Comment: do you mean a single column whose value is like 2013-04-01,science,96

Comment: Also in your question, code snippet, you want to know the result corresponding to a single rowKey. I am not getting the whole thing properly. Need to be clarified

Comment: See this is the column family structure in my app `
rowkey  studentinfo
1       | 2013-04-01,science,96
2 | 2013-04-01,science,96
 | 2013-04-02,maths,96
 | 2012-04-03,english,90`    I want to query row by row on each column

Comment: `rowkey  studentinfo` `1  | 2013-04-01,science,96` `2  | 2013-04-01,science,96
  | 2013-04-02,maths,96
  | 2012-04-03,english,90`

Comment: @abhi, I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921964/composite-column-values-in-cassandra). Can you please take a look?